# Weird issue in navigation when in Safari Browser

Tags: html, safari, href

I have navigation bar in my website that makes the links work properly everywhere.  But when on Safari, for some reason the links are not clickable unless you highlight the empty space above the option.  I diagnosed it further to find that I was adding a negative margin-top for the searchbox to align it properly with the options, when I removed that margin-top, the links were clickable.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a z-index and position:absolute to make sure your navigation Div is on top. thats more than likely what the problem is.
Try that... add

```
z-index:100px;
position:absolute;
```

to your navigation in css.